# array filter in javascript value coming as not expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
const secret = [
  {key:'1'},
  {key:'2'}
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting output should be the second object in the array as key:2. Which part I am trying is  wrong.As I am getting output as `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

this part of the code

```
secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1});
```

returns an array because it filters all the items in the original array (called secret in this case) and selects all the elements respecting the condition (>1 in this case).

if you're sure just one item is the one you need, just add [0] and the key at the end:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1})[0]['key'];
```

or you could use a cycle to get all the values selected

```
const allgoodvalues = secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1});
allgoodvalues.forEach((element) =>
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += element['key']
});
```

something like this should fix your problem!
i would personally use the last fix... it's more scalable

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
console.log(
    secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1})
);
```

in the console you'll see the `.filter` call is returning an array:

```
[ { key: "2" } ]
```

But whether you get an array `[...]` or an object `{...}`, when you're assigning it as the value to innerHTML, it's becoming casted as a string. e.g., it's doing, `String( [{key:"2"}] )`.

And if you try `console.log(String( [] ))` or `console.log(String( {} ))` you'll see that both yield the `"[object Object]"` that you're seeing.

---

If you want it to print the object construct, you'll want to convert it to JSON. e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
    secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1})
)
```

yields `"[{key:"2"}]"`

---

If you want just the object, you may want to try the `.find` function instead:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
    secret.find((value)=>{return value.key>1})
)
```

yields `"{key:"2"}"`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the second entry, but you are sending it to the DOM and it's serialising it as `[object Object]` to tell you that you have an object of type object. You can make it JSON, and then print it by wrapping the statement in `JSON.stringify()`. That will print out `[{"key":"2"}]` instead of `[object Object]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
const secret = [
  {key:'1'},
  {key:'2'}
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1}));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
const secret = [
  {key:'1'},
  {key:'2'}
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(secret.filter((value)=>{return value.key>1}));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).